# Getting GTest to work with Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: windows, googletest

The Visual Studio Test Explorer is not seeing the errors reported in GTest.

Visual Studio 2017 C++ build with GTest Unit Test Project. Builds fine, debug into the test, shows error but not being picked up by Visual Studio Test Explorer, is showing test ran without an error.

```
TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(1, 3);
}
```

The test should fail and show up in Test Explorer with red check mark.

Comment: Have you tried installing the [Google Test Adapter](https://github.com/csoltenborn/GoogleTestAdapter) extension/plugin in visual studio?

That extension integrates the Google Tests into Visual Studio's Test Explorer rather well.

Answer (score 0):

Plese have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp?view=vs-2017 to see Microsoft's description of how to install and use *Google Test Adapter*.

There is also Jetbrains's [ReSharpter C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) available, which provides a very nice integration of GoogleTest into VS.

Comment: If I have a project, is it only when I create a Google Test
Project and connect it with my project, will the test results be displayed in the test explorer?

I created the *.sln project and installed gtest with vcpkg. Every time I test the project, the result will only appear in the terminal.